# Call outer synchronized method from anonymous inner class in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

Is it safe and correct to call a synchronized method from an anonymous inner class?
Is the lock monitor in the outer class correctly acquired?

This is a small extract of the code that shows what I mean.

Is there any issue in leaving the code like this or I would better to change it?

```
class OuterClass {

   public synchronized Object getValue(String id) { .... }

   public synchronized getValueFunction(String id) {
      
      return new GetValueInnerInterface() {
          @Override
          public Object getValueInner(String id) {
              return getValue(id);
          }
      }      
   } 

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized void foo() {
  code();
}
```

is just syntax sugar. It's the exact same thing as:

```
void foo() {
  synchronized (this) {
    code();
  }
}
```

Had `foo` been static, and in a class named `class Example {}`, it's short for:

```
static void foo() {
  synchronized (Example.class) {
    code();
  }
}
```

Which therefore means putting 'synchronized' on a method is **almost always wrong**. Locks are important things and if you 'leak' them, then you need to document your locking behaviour. Ordinarily, you want your locks to be **private**, which means the right move is usually:

```
public class Example {
  private final Object locker = new Object();

  public void doSomethingSynchronized() {
    synchronized (locker) {
      code();
    }
  }
}
```

But, if you really want to go with public locks (given that `Example.class` is something other code not under your control can also lock on, and usually, `this` also is made available to code outside of your direct control), then make sure to document it, and this also means you must continue to support the lock behaviour as you documented it forevermore (well, that, or, break backwards compatibility).

Given that this is how it works, yes, of course, if you call these methods from within an anonymous inner class, or anywhere else, they will lock on what `this` would mean **within the context of the method that has the `synchronized` keyword on it** (so, an instance of the outer, not an instance of the inner).

Note that sticking a `synchronized` on a `getValueFunction` method seems useless: There is nothing that this function does which requires synchronization, as written.

Also, generally, 'just toss a synchronized keyword everywhere like it is going out of style' is a very bad way to achieve thread safety (as in, it won't actually give you thread safety and slow everything down to a crawl).